# Oracle 12c: installing expdp and impdp on Linux

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, impdp, expdp

The default Oracle installation for Linux didn't come with the expdp and impdp command line tools. I have trouble finding them on Oracle's website. How could I install them?

Comment: They were installed, just missing from my `$PATH`. See the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data Pump utilities are installed automatically during the installation of Oracle Database. It should be working without any issues as long as the environment variables(`PATH`, `ORACLE_HOME`) are set properly. To set `PATH` and `ORACLE_HOME` variable permanently-

1) Log in as oracle user in the OS.

2) `[oracle@ora12c Desktop]$ vi ~/.bash_profile`

```
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle; export ORACLE_BASE
ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/12.1.0/db_1; export ORACLE_HOME
PATH=.:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}:$HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

3)`[oracle@ora12c Desktop]$ . ~/.bash_profile`

4)Check the value of the variables.

```
[oracle@ora12c Desktop]$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1
[oracle@ora12c ~]$ echo $PATH
.:/usr/local/java/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/oracle/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/local/bin:/u01/app/common/oracle/bin
```

5) Try to run expdp

```
[oracle@ora12c Desktop]$ expdp 

Export: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Tue Oct 4 16:46:44 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Username:
```

[Setting Oracle Environment Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UNXAR/admin_ora.htm#UNXAR115)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just needed to log in with "oracle" user instead of root. This user had all the environment variables correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

If logged in as **opc** user you'd have to

```
$sudo su - oracle
```

first and then the environment has everything you need